# Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, cherrypy

My requirement is to plot one bar graph on a webpage with cherrypy and matplotlib. I am able to load the graph but cant get the coordinates onmouseover
of plot. Can anybody suggest how can I get the coordinates.Do I have to use javascript or matplotlib can fulfill the requirement.
The code looks simialr to this

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class HelloWorld:

    def index(self):
        fig = plt.figure()
         ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
         ax.plot([1,2,3])
         fig.savefig('test.png')
        return ''' <img src="test.png" width="640" height="480" border="0" /> '''

    index.exposed = True

import os.path
tutconf = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'tutorial.conf')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld(), config=tutconf)
else:
    cherrypy.tree.mount(HelloWorld(), config=tutconf)
```

Comment: If you want to stay with Python code while having interactive charts, take a look at [`plotly`](https://plot.ly/matplotlib/) and its `matplotlib` integration.

Answer (score 2):

> My requirement is to plot one bar graph on a webpage with cherrypy and
>   matplotlib.

So, if that is your only requirement, you are close to your solution: create the plot file server-side and deliver it to the client.

However, it seems that this is not the only requirement (you really need to better express what you want to achieve when you ask others for help):

> cant get the coordinates onmouseover of plot

This is something that has to happen client-side, i.e. within the browser. Hence, this is a task for JavaScript code executed by the browser in the context of your website.

So, if you are forced to using JavaScript anyway, maybe it would be better to serve the client (browser) only the data and let the plotting be handled by one of the many JavaScript plotting frameworks. That way, you save some load on the server (matplotlib plotting actually is pretty CPU intense) and also save bandwidth.

You may want to look at http://www.chartjs.org.

Comment: But with matplotlib I can load the plot on webpage(by saving image in a static file and showing it when user wants to see the plot and clicks on show graph button, show graph is a button on that website) but if user points to any point on the plot he can't get the coordinates so how do I do that?